# "How to fix 'Signing Report while opening an emulator"

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android . i am working on connecting my app to firebase. Now my problem is this "When i try running my emulator, my signing report will keep  on showing as an error which will not allow me to run my code ". please how can i fix this?.

i have tried rebuilding my project and check my firebase codes but they are not showing error

whenever i try running an emulator this is what shows as an error. please i need help.

Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\BLAKOUS.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: E6:4F:FA:50:F0:95:D6:6E:D9:4B:94:59:2A:1E:7C:21
SHA1: AF:A1:61:78:9E:6A:1B:5D:4B:16:DE:FE:AE:95:44:43:79:49:A9:93

### Valid until: Sunday, June 6, 2049

Variant: release

### Config: none

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
6:06:16 AM: Task execution finished 'signingReport'.

This signing report is not meant to be showing when i run my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this.

Please change from **signingreport** to **app**. Like this - please see attached screenshot.

[image]

then try to run your code.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped

Comment: @Raj - Just accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: I have one question. My Signing report not produces new SHA key bro different flavour?

Comment: I have many different flavour with different .Jks